# Sequence problems!

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Sequences (make sure to look in a fiction book!)

MROGVW, tVPGaML, BdAMaC, **?**, IPaUPC, aODFCtV, EHMbtH, **?**, **?**, **?**, GGaL, IGSwaP, WVtJotG, IHaDP, IWSET, WMtDoEBB, IPoaFMEP, AFSG, **?**, IGaNEfC

What are the question marks! (Caps count (sort of))

**HINT 1:** (this is *too* broad)

> Chapter Four is a car accident, though not the kind you'd expect.

Comment: _Any_ fiction book, or do you have a specific one in mind? If you have a specific one in mind, perhaps you could give us a clue as to what it is. There are a _lot_ of fiction books in existence.

Comment: Ok! I'll do a quote from the book.

Comment: Oh yeah, so I'll change that.

Comment: @TzuLi: have my capitals been reflected more accurately now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the hints, this appears to be

> chapter titles from [The Titan’s Curse, by Rick Riordan](https://riordan.fandom.com/wiki/The_Titan%27s_Curse).

It follows that the missing question marks are

> TTNE (Thalia Torches New England) 
>  IMaDP (I Make a Dangerous Promise) 
>  ILHtGZ (I Learn How to Grow Zombies) 
>  IBaFRS (I Break a Few Rocket Ships) 
>  TGVHtKU (The Gods Vote How to Kill Us).